# Modify columns by specific duplicated columns in data.table

Tags: r, datatable

I have this `data.table`:

| case | exclusion 1 | exclusion 2 | exclusion 3 | exclusion 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T | F | T | T |
| 1 | T | F | F | T |
| 1 | F | F | F | T |
| 2 | F | F | T | F |
| 3 | T | F | F | F |
| 3 | F | F | F | F |

There is a column with `case`, there are 3 cases and 2 cases are duplicated. I have 4 exclusion-columns with True or FALSE. If there are any exclusion-columns for duplicated cases TRUE and FALSE, I want to change the TRUE in FALSE. If all specific exclusions are TRUE or FALSE by case there is nothing to do. This table should look like this:

| case | exclusion 1 | exclusion 2 | exclusion 3 | exclusion 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | F | F | T |
| 1 | F | F | F | T |
| 1 | F | F | F | T |
| 2 | F | F | T | F |
| 3 | F | F | F | F |
| 3 | F | F | F | F |

I need this table format, because then I can do a unique by case and then I have this table:

| case | exclusion 1 | exclusion 2 | exclusion 3 | exclusion 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | F | F | T |
| 2 | F | F | T | F |
| 3 | F | F | F | F |

This last step is clear. But how can I get the second table?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's you're intermediate result:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, \(x) rep(all(x), .N)), by = case]
#    case exclusion 1 exclusion 2 exclusion 3 exclusion 4
# 1:    1       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
# 2:    1       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
# 3:    1       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
# 4:    2       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
# 5:    3       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
# 6:    3       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
```

Though it's less work to go directly to the end result:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, all), by = case]
#    case exclusion 1 exclusion 2 exclusion 3 exclusion 4
# 1:    1       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
# 2:    2       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
# 3:    3       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
```

---

Using this data:

```
dt = fread(text = 'case     exclusion 1     exclusion 2     exclusion 3     exclusion 4
1   T   F   T   T
1   T   F   F   T
1   F   F   F   T
2   F   F   T   F
3   T   F   F   F
3   F   F   F   F')
```

---

#### Keeping extra columns:

```
dt2 = fread(text = 'case     exclusion1     exclusion2     exclusion3     exclusion4
1   T   F   T   T
1   T   F   F   T
1   F   F   F   T
2   F   F   T   F
3   T   F   F   F
3   F   F   F   F')

cols = paste0("exclusion", 1:4)
dt2[, extra_col := "hi"]
dt2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, all), by = case, .SDcols = cols]
dt2
#    case exclusion1 exclusion2 exclusion3 exclusion4 extra_col
# 1:    1      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE        hi
# 2:    1      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE        hi
# 3:    1      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE        hi
# 4:    2      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE        hi
# 5:    3      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE        hi
# 6:    3      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE        hi
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Hm this doesn't work, because there are some more columns beside case and exclusion, also with other column types. So he tries to convert all columns to boolean. Is there another way without using all?

Comment: You can specify the column names you want to apply to in `.SDcols`, e.g., `dt[, lapply(.SD, \(x) rep(all(x), .N)), by = case, .SDcols = paste("exclusion", 1:4)]`. Or if the other columns have the same values within each case, you can add them to the `by` argument.

Comment: Thank you again. Yes this works, but now all other columns except case/exclusion are gone. It there a way, that the other columns stay in dt?

Comment: You can have your vector of column names and use `(cols) := lapply(...)`. See edits in the "Keeping extra columns" section.

Comment: Is there a way, to change the logic? One of the exclusion-columns for duplicated cases with TRUE and FALSE, I want to change the FALSE in TRUE (and not the TRUE in FALSE). But only for one exclusion, for example exclusion1.

Comment: Use `any()` instead of `all()` for that column.